# German abbreviations for instrument names in score markings (Wagner - Tannhauser)

Tags: orchestra, orchestration

I'd like to know to which instruments are these signatures referring. I think "Pos" is a trombone but I may be wrong.

[image]

Please note these are from page 2 of Wagner's Tannhauser ouverture and, most likely, the abbreviation is in German language.

Additionally, I'd like to know if "zu 3" means something about how many instruments are supposed to play the part or not.

Comment: Good answers.  I'll just put in a plug for buying one of the encylopedias of musical terms.  The Harvard Ency' is decent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posaunen:  Trombones.  Btb:  Bass Tuba.  Pk:  Pauken = tympani.

zu 3 = all three trombones play the same notes.

Comment: // "T***i***mpani", not "tympani".

Answer (score 14):

Wagner was German, so the instrument names are in German. (*Die Posa* is Latin for "placed on")

Yes, Pos. is short for *Posuane*, German for trombone.

Btb. is short for *Basstuba*, German for Bass tuba (duh :P)

Pk. is short for *Pauken*, German for Timpani

zu 3 is short for *zusammen drei*, German for (literally) "three together"

Comment: +1 thanks for your help. I'm sorry but I can accept only one answer and the other guy posted first even if your is correct as well.

Answer (score 11):

[Here is a comprehensive chart from Yale University Library](http://www.library.yale.edu/cataloging/music/instname.htm) which provides the names of all the major orchestral instruments, and more, in

- English
- French
- German
- Italian
- Russian (albeit in the Latin alphabet)
- Spanish

It does *not* provide a list of the common abbreviations like the ones in your example score. It provides the full names of each instrument in each language, and notes synonyms or alternate names. However, you should still find it to be a useful reference source.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other sources:

- Instrument abbreviations in two languages *(French, English)* from
  Laval university of Canada 
  [Abréviations des instruments de musique](http://www.mus.ulaval.ca/roberge/gdrm/08-instr.htm)
- Extensive information about instrumentation, nomenclature,
  abbreviations *(English, Italian, German, French, Spanish)*
  orchestral setup and much more from Dolmetsch Organisation 
  [Musical instrument ranges & names](http://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory29.htm#translatednames)